# Extract files from zip folder and store these files in blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unzip, blobstore

i want to upload zip folder from file input in form the i want to extract the contents of this uploaded zip folder,and store the contents (files)of this zip in the blobstore in order to download them after putting these files in one folder,but the problem is that i can't deal with the zip folder directly(to read it), i tried as this:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
file_upload = form['file']
zip1=file_upload.filename
zipstream=StringIO.StringIO(zip1.read())
```

But the problem still that i can't read the zip as previous,also i tried to read zip folder directly like this:

```
z1=zipfile.ZipFile(zip1,"r")
```

But there was an error in this way.Please can any one help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: In general, it helps if you post your errors.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you need to take a closer look at the [cgi module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html), which includes the following:

> If a field represents an uploaded file, accessing the value via the `value` attribute or the `getvalue()` method reads the entire file in memory as a string. This may not be what you want. You can test for an uploaded file by testing either the `filename` attribute or the `file` attribute. You can then read the data at leisure from the `file` attribute...

This suggests that you need to modify your code to look something like:

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
file_upload = form['file']
z1 = zipfile.ZipFile(file_upload.file, 'r')
```

There are additional examples in the documentation.

Comment: :the problem when i write :zipstream=StringIO.StringIO(zip1.read()) is :'str' object has no attribute 'read'(so i can't read the uploaded zip)so i tried to use :z1=zipfile.ZipFile(zip1,"r") without zipstream usage but the error is i can't read the uploaded zip directly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to extract files from the zip in order to make them available for download - see [this post](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/08/Using-BlobReader-wildcard-subdomains-and-webapp2) for an example of serving direct from a zip. You can adapt that code if you want to extract the files and store them individually in the blobstore.

Comment: @ Nick Johnson:I'm sorry but i don't understand this post exactly,you mean that no need to extract the files from zip,but how this is possible??i need to do this and upload these files into blobstore,please i want a help??

Comment: :Yes,i'm sorry i didn't understand this post!!

Comment: @Eng_Engineer Tell me what you didn't understand about it, and I'll attempt to clarify. It walks through building pretty much exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: @ Nick Johnson:i saw the demo after reading the post,this is for upload zip and there is site fileld in the demo, i didn't understand what is this field exactly about??.Thanks

Comment: @Eng_Engineer That field is for the name of the subdomain you want to serve the zip file off. It's specific to the demo - it doesn't have to work that way.

Comment: @ Nick Johnson:also i have two main functions in my application (compress files and decompress zip file)the compress function still have the problem that i can't download(serve) the zip file from the blobstore after uploading(creating zip and storing files that submitted by the user in blobstore) it to the blob

Comment: @ Nick Johnson:do you mean the blobstore in my application?

Comment: @Eng_Engineer As I said, the sample demonstrates everything you're asking for help doing, except for extracting individual files from the zip into new blobs - which is straightforward with this as a foundation, and not necessary in any case. If you have something specific about the code that you don't understand, ask, and I'll attempt to clarify.

Comment: @ Nick Johnson:Ok i will try to do this ,thank you very much for your help,but i want to ask in the site field if i put my blob storage link and upload zip file from my computer then this file store in the blobstore????Thanks again,i will read the code and if i have any problem i will ask you.Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9239/discussion-between-eng-engineer-and-nick-johnson)